# Generalized First Price Auction or Generalized Second Price?

Tags: game-theory, finance

Sorry if I ask the same question again but in the other post I'm not able to edit my question because I wasn't using an account. 
By the way, the question: 
I'm running some tests to decide which type of auction is better. My settings are set randomly, I mean that budgets are random, advs' value are random .... My goal is to maximize the revenue. Which one I should use?

Please note that advs' values are adjusted based upon the previous auctions (using an history).

P.S. My tests show that FPA is a little better than GSP. I draw my conclusion: let's suppose this setting: 2 advs and 3 slots:
advs' values are 5 and 3, so in FPA the revenue is 5+3 = 8 but in GSP is 3+0 because there isn't a 3rd adv. So revenue(FPA)>revenue(GSP). It this right?

Answer (score 2):

Did you check for the equilibria of each game? In a FPA players do not bid their valuations so you can't compute the revenues as such. The same for the GSP, it depends according to which Nash equilibrium bidders will behave. Then, what are the ctrs associated to both positions?

Anyway have a look on this [paper](http://research.microsoft.com/en-us/um/people/brlucier/misc/gsp-revenue-www2012.pdf) and this [one](https://www.cs.duke.edu/courses/spring07/cps296.3/fp185-lahaie.pdf), hope it will be useful for your problem.